# Deserializing a complex Json in Java with Map Data Type

Tags: java, json, jackson, deserialization, json-deserialization

I have the following JSON object that is parsed through a HTTP request.

```
{
 "firstName": "User",
 "lastName": "Test",
 "emailId": "testnew@gmail.com",
 "formsAndQuestions": {
   "Form1": {
      "Question1": {
        "value": "NEVER",
       "isBoolean": false
      },
      "Question2": {
        "value": "YES"
      }
    },
    "Form2": {
      "Question1": {
        "value": "OTHER"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The form object can be dynamic. Therefore I'm deserializing this in my Java class with the following variable.

```
Map<String, Map<String, Map<String, String>>> forms;
```

Then I'm going through the complex loop below to iterate these and read the answer values.

```
for (Map.Entry<String, Map<String, Map<String, String>>> entry : input.formsAndQuestions().get().entrySet()) {
        logger.log("Form: " + entry.getKey());
        for (Map.Entry<String, Map<String, String>> entry1 : entry.getValue().entrySet()) {
            logger.log("Question: " + entry1.getKey());
            for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry2 : entry1.getValue().entrySet()) {
                logger.log("key: " + entry2.getKey());
                logger.log("value: " + entry2.getValue());
            }
        }
    }
```

Is there a better way to do this? Loop seems pretty complex. I don't want to create a Java object class for deserializing the json as the "formsAndQuestions" object can have multiple forms added/removed with multiple questions/answers per form added or removed.

Would greatly appreciate any feedback on this approach.

Comment: Instead of Map, you can use JsonNode of Jackson library. See this link  https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-json-to-jsonnode option #4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even so forms and questions vary, the structure is the same. You can easily model this in `Java` using `@JsonAnySetter` annotation to set properly random forms. Take a look on below example:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAnySetter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.ToString;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class FormsAndQuestionsApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        File jsonFile = new File("./resource/test.json").getAbsoluteFile();

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        Result result = mapper.readValue(jsonFile, Result.class);
        result.getFormsAndQuestions().getForms().forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}

@Data
@ToString
class Result {

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String emailId;
    private FormsAndQuestions formsAndQuestions;
}

@Data
@ToString
class FormsAndQuestions {
    private List<Form> forms = new ArrayList<>();

    @JsonAnySetter
    public void anySetter(String formName, Map<String, Question> questions) {
        // update questions with keys (question's name)
        questions.forEach((k, v) -> v.setQuestion(k));

        forms.add(new Form(formName, questions.values()));
    }
}

@Data
@ToString
@AllArgsConstructor
class Form {

    private String name;
    private Collection<Question> questions;
}

@Data
@ToString
class Question {
    private String question;
    private String value;
    private Boolean isBoolean;
}
```

Above code prints:

```
Form(name=Form1, questions=[Question(question=Question1, value=NEVER, isBoolean=false), Question(question=Question2, value=YES, isBoolean=null)])
Form(name=Form2, questions=[Question(question=Question1, value=OTHER, isBoolean=null)])
```

The key point is `public void anySetter(String formName, Map<String, Question> questions)` method. Using `@JsonAnySetter` we convert `JSON Object` to a list, because for every unknown `key-value` pair this method will be invoked. Also, we convert inner object to proper `Question` `POJO`. `value` field is set by `Jackson` we need to set `question` property only. Right now, it should be much easier to traverse this list and use later in some business logic.

Comment: @Michael Ziober I have a related question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63747082/getting-cannot-construct-instance-exception-when-using-immutables-to-deseriali. Would you be able to help with this one?